# Ubuntu Installing error

Tags: 16.04, command-line, apt, package-management, software-installation

Every time I'm trying to install something, it shows me an error "unable to locate package xxx"

```
$ sudo apt-get install gddrescue
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gddrescue

sudo apt-get install testdisk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Is that normal...? (Thanks for correcting)

```
sudo apt update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
    Release:        16.04
    Codename:       xenial

Comment: gddrescue is provided by the **universe** repository in 16.04. Check that universe is enabled in Software & Updates (Dash -> Software & Updates).

Comment: The problem is i can't install anything even to update...

Comment: Can you add the output of `sudo apt update` please?

Comment: The update command doesn't seem to load any package sources. Did you comment/remove/disable any of the software sources? Can you show us the output of  `grep -r --include '*.list' ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list*` ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: When you get **Unable to Locate Package xxx**, goto https://packages.ubuntu.com and search for the package name. You'll find in your case that `gddrescue` is available under `universe`. Thus, we need to add it. Try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gddrescue
```

Comment: Probably not. But I thought it would be better if it's available also. For some other software OP tries to download in future.

Comment: @Melebius Removed `multiverse` from my answer.